# Bad security certificate for meta.codereview.stackexchange.com

Tags: bug, status-deferred

When I browse to [`https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/`](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/) using Firefox, I get a message that the security certificate is bad because it's for `*.stackexchange.com` and `*.meta.stackexchange.com` (among others). I have to add an exception in order to view the meta site.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a known issue (yeah, sucky answer).

It has been known for years, and the fix is likely not going to arrive any time soon.

In reality, you probably have not been using https to connect to meta, so you have not noticed. The login and so on work fine, it's just the actual `meta.*.stackexchange.com` sites (meta.stackexchage.com works fine...).

The issue is related to the need to create unreasonably many certificates because the wildcard `*` in the certified domains only goes one sub-domain deep.

[Nick Craver's blog explains this a lot better](http://nickcraver.com/blog/2013/04/23/stackoverflow-com-the-road-to-ssl/)

Useful links:

- https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8061/ssl-error-on-meta
- [Untrusted connection when visiting per-site meta over SSL](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216384/untrusted-connection-when-visiting-meta-stack-exchange-sites)

Comment: Usually I just use http to connect to meta.*.SE but I had found a link inside help that used https. But now I can't find it any more!